# How do I print an object property in the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the `rails console` and I'm trying to loop through an array of objects, and print just one of their properties, say for example, the `name` property.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

`Model.all.map(&:name)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use pluck method for fetching attributes.

```
Model.pluck(:name)
```